# Custom UICollectionViewCell drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I custom `UICollectionViewCell` which includes few `UIImageView` `subview`s. I don't know the number of `UIImageView`s before photoInfo dictionary parameter send into this cell. So I created

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary* photoInfo;

-(void) setPhotoInfo:(NSDictionary *)photoInfo{
      ......
}
```

I init all UIImageViews in `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

But I have to know how many `UIImageView`s I need to create.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
NSArray *photos = [self.photoInfo objectForKey:@"photos"];
    if (photos && photos.count) {
        int i = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *photoInfo in photos) {
            //create UIImageView here
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [self.contentView addSubView:imgView];
        }
     }
 }
```

The problem is when `drawRect` is called, setPhotoInfo:(NSDictionary *)photoInfo hasn't been called yet, so I can't get self.photoInfo, then none of `UIImageView` is created. Any better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in drawRect.  What if you just change your setter to look like this:

```
-(void) setPhotoInfo:(NSDictionary *)photoInfo
{
    if(_photoInfo != photoInfo)
    {
        _photoInfo = photoInfo;
        [self.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        NSArray *photos = _photoInfo[@"photos"];
        for (NSDictionary *photoInfo in photos) {
            //create UIImageView here
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [self.contentView addSubView:imgView];
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you update the dictionary it will clear out all the subviews and add them to the content view.  When you add the new layer to the content view it will automatically redraw itself.  Of course your creating empty UIImageViews in your sample so you wont see anything until you actually put an image in them.